# Application specific users table or mysql.users

Tags: mysql, security, users

I am using a mysql installation that handles an application with multiple users. These users have varying permissions for table access, but also need to be referenced within tables in the application database. For example, I have a manufacturer table that stores the person who manufactured a batch, but different manufacturers have different access to the tables.
If I weren't referencing them within the application tables I would use the mysql.users table to handle permissions, and if I weren't giving users variable permissions then I would use a local users table.
Is there a standard and secure way of handling this sort of situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a feature like *Oracle Virtual Private Database*. Unfortunately MySQL does not have this. There is a similar question with answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527129/mysql-how-to-do-row-level-security-like-oracles-virtual-private-database.

Comment: @Marco, will be helpful if you edit your answer and add some other information not only the link, so, if others have the same problem, they could easily find the answer.